# Awk progrand to validate 3 files with different fields

Tags: shell, awk

I'm writting a awk program to valid 3 files.
here file 1 will have 5 fields, file2 will have 4 fields, file3 will have 2 fields

```
first coulm in first row matches with the condition, move to next record orelse exit on each file
for example if (NR == 1 && $1 == "NAME") {next}
         else {exit 1}
for first file from second row validate the 2nd column should not be null
for second file from second row validate the 01st column should not be null, and 03rd column should not be null
for third file from second row validate the 01st column should not be null
```

SAMPLE files

```
file1: SUN_20200801.csv
NAME|AGE|JOIN|END|QUIT
AAA|23|Y|2021|N
BBB|25|N|2022|N

file2: MOON_20200801.csv
EMPNO|EMPNAME|EMPSAL|EMPDEP
01|XXXX|20000|SE
01|YYYY|30000|NSE

file3: STAR_20200801.csv
DEPNO|DEPNAME
01|XXXX
01|YYYY
```

**CODE I TRIED**

```
BEGIN { FS="|"
}

#MAIN PROGRAM
{
  if (NR == 1 && $1 != "NAME") {
         if (NR == 1 && $1 != "EMPNO") {
                if (NR == 1 && $1 != "DEPNO") { print "HEADER NOT MATCHING"
                                                  exit 1}}}
 if (NR == 1 && $1 == "NAME")               
     { next        
    if (NR > 1)
       { if ( NF != 5 ) { print "Input record does not contain 5 fields" }
          else { if ( NF = 5 ) { if ( $2 == "" ) { print "IS NULL" } }}
        }
      }


 if (NR == 1 && $1 == "EMPNO")
 { next 
    if (NR > 1)
       { if ( NF != 4 ){ print "Input record does not contain 4 fields" }
          else { if ( NF = 4 ) { if ( $1 == "" ) { print "IS NULL" } 
                                  if ( $1 == "" ) { print "IS NULL" } 
                                }
                }
        }
  }
       
 if (NR == 1 && $1 == "DEPNO")
 {next 
    if (NR > 1)
       { if ( NF != 2 ) { print "Input record does not contain 2 fields" }
          else {if ( NF = 2 ) { if ( $1 == "" ) { print "IS NULL" } } }
        }
  }
}
```

Here that "next" is not working. Could anyone of you help me to write correct code?

---

EDIT by Ed Morton to show the above code run through `gawk -o-` to make the structure easier to follow:

```
BEGIN {
        FS = "|"
}

{
        if (NR == 1 && $1 != "NAME") {
                if (NR == 1 && $1 != "EMPNO") {
                        if (NR == 1 && $1 != "DEPNO") {
                                print "HEADER NOT MATCHING"
                                exit 1
                        }
                }
        }
        if (NR == 1 && $1 == "NAME") {
                next
                if (NR > 1) {
                        if (NF != 5) {
                                print "Input record does not contain 5 fields"
                        } else if (NF = 5) {
                                if ($2 == "") {
                                        print "IS NULL"
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        if (NR == 1 && $1 == "EMPNO") {
                next
                if (NR > 1) {
                        if (NF != 4) {
                                print "Input record does not contain 4 fields"
                        } else if (NF = 4) {
                                if ($1 == "") {
                                        print "IS NULL"
                                }
                                if ($1 == "") {
                                        print "IS NULL"
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        if (NR == 1 && $1 == "DEPNO") {
                next
                if (NR > 1) {
                        if (NF != 2) {
                                print "Input record does not contain 2 fields"
                        } else if (NF = 2) {
                                if ($1 == "") {
                                        print "IS NULL"
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}

#MAIN PROGRAM
```

Comment: `next` will not bring you back to the if-then-else condition where you left-off, it will reevaluate from the beginning.

Comment: I ran  your code through a pretty-printer (`gawk -o-`) to make it easier to see what it's doing - look at it and you'll see multiple places where it just doesn't make sense, e.g. code after a `next`, multiple back-to-back tests for `$1 == ""` in the same block, nested `if`s all testing for `NR == 1`, assignments like `NF = 5` when you intend a comparison `NF == 5`, testing for `$1 == ""` inside blocks you entered by testing for it not being `""`, etc. Use what I posted as a starting point and clean up all the obvious issues then ask again if you still have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be useful for you to solve the problem yourself, so here is a structure you can follow instead of your own and substitute the logic when necessary.

Essentially, from the first line identify the file type and use that in the following validation checks.  It will be useful to mark where the failure happened.  You may not want to exit at the first error as I did here.

```
$ awk FS='|' 'FNR==1{if($1=="NAME")  f=1;
                else if($1=="EMPNO") f=2;
                else if($1=="DEPNO") f=3;
                else {print "unknown: "$1; exit 1}
              next}

       # now we're not on the first record anymore
       # but f is set to either 1,2, or 3.
       f==1 && NF!=5  {print "Input record does not contain 5 fields"; exit 1}
       f==1 && $2=="" {print "2nd field is null"; exit 1}
   
       f==2 && NF!=4  {print "Input record does not contain 4 fields"; exit 1}
       ...
       }' file1 file2 file3
```

by using `FNR` you can check all three files in one run as well.